# Center in parent is not working for custom relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to create custom layout "SquareBox" based on relative layout to hold a ImageView in center.
And this custom layout will always be in square size (depend on ImageView's height and width).

```
protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
    super.onMeasure(width, height);
    int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    int size;
    if (measuredWidth > measuredHeight) {
        size = measuredWidth;
    } else {
        size = measuredHeight;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
}
```

Here is my layout code:

```
  <com.example.tools.SquareBox
        android:id="@+id/square_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/canvas_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        tools:src="@drawable/demo_image" />
</com.example.tools.SquareBox>
```

It is working fine but the image-view is not in center of this custom view.
I've tried following:
->android:layout_centerInParent="true" for ImageView.

->android:gravity="center" for "SquareBox".

->Adding CENTER_IN_PARENT programmatically to ImageView in SquareBox's onMeasure method.

But nothing is working.
What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have emulated the square box behavior in another way. I think it's a workaround and It may be not the best solution but it works. I would like to know better and cleaner solution.

Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/square_box_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/square_box"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/canvas_image"
            style="@style/CanvasImageStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            tools:src="@drawable/demo_image2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code to resize the view:

```
 squareImageView.setImageBitmap(getResultBitmap());
            squareBoxHolder.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    squareBoxHolder.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    Log.i(TAG, "onPreDraw: squareBoxHolder");
                    squareBoxHolderSize = new Point(squareBoxHolder.getMeasuredWidth(), squareBoxHolder.getMeasuredHeight());
                    return true;
                }
            });
            squareImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    squareImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    Log.i(TAG, "onPreDraw: squareImageView");
                    int imageWidth = squareImageView.getMeasuredWidth();
                    int imageHeight = squareImageView.getMeasuredHeight();
                    int size;
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = squareImageView.getLayoutParams();
                    if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
                        if (imageWidth > squareBoxHolderSize.y) {
                            size = squareBoxHolderSize.y;
                            layoutParams.width = size;
                            squareImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        } else {
                            size = imageWidth;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (imageHeight > squareBoxHolderSize.x) {
                            size = squareBoxHolderSize.x;
                            layoutParams.height = size;
                            squareImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        } else {
                            size = imageHeight;
                        }
                    }

                    layoutParams = squareBox.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.height = size;
                    layoutParams.width = size;
                    squareBox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your layout to this (change `layout_width` to `match_parent`)  :

```
<com.example.tools.SquareBox
        android:id="@+id/square_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/canvas_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        tools:src="@drawable/demo_image" />
</com.example.tools.SquareBox>
```

And change your custom layout to this:

```
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int size;
    if(widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && widthSize > 0){
      size = widthSize;
    }
    else if(heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && heightSize > 0){
      size = heightSize;
    }
    else{
      size = widthSize < heightSize ? widthSize : heightSize;
    }

    int finalMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(finalMeasureSpec, finalMeasureSpec);
  }
```

Comment: I have tried this. It does center the image in custom view. But after resizing of custom view, ImageView still remains in center based on previous size which makes it get cropped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-`android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`